# thyself = yourself, what is the equivalent of *others*?

Tags: single-word-requests, early-modern-english, literary-english

Is there a Shakespeare style of saying *others*?

**Example:**

> Know yourself, know *others*
>
> Know thyself, know ____

By *others* I mean other people in general. Could be an intended group but not enemy.

Comment: There's no such direct equivalent "reflexive pronoun", because ***others*** isn't a pronoun. The nearest you can get is probably [*Know the selves of others.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22know+the+selves+of+others%22)

Comment: Try it out here - https://funtranslations.com/shakespeare

Comment: There is no equivalent for "*others*" in Shakespearean language.

Comment: Maybe: Know thyself, know the people.

Comment: @Justin Isn't 'others' the right word in Early Modern English?

Comment: Thanks! What about themselves?

Comment: @Jalene No, *them* is the same in EME and Modern English, so *themselves* is the same too. When translating into EME, people often make the mistake of changing much too much. It's true constructions may change, but only **certain forms** of words do. Thus "It seems to me that you're giving too much away" might become "Thou dost reveal too much, methinks" (not *revealest,* although *dost* takes the *-st* ending).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only significant differences in Early Modern English (the English of Shakespeare) is in the form of the second person singular (thou/thee/thy) and the verb forms of second and third person singular (thou sayest, he saith).

These follow into singular reflexive pronouns, because the *your* of *yourself* is *thy,* so it's *thyself. Yourselves* doesn't change, because *you/your* is the correct EME plural.

*Others* doesn't change. Here it is after a preposition, which would normally be an object (*me, thee*):

> Kneel not to me:
>   The power that I have on you is, to spare you;
>   The malice towards you to forgive you: live,
>   And deal with others better.